# Error in Accumulo's tablet server when scanning for data

Tags: hadoop, accumulo

I have a bunch of tables in Accumulo with one master and 2 tablet servers containing a bunch of tables storing millions of records. The problem is that whenever I scan the tables to get a few records out, the tablet server logs keep throwing this error

```
2015-11-12 04:38:56,107 [hdfs.DFSClient] WARN : Failed to connect to /192.168.250.12:50010 for block, add to deadNodes and continue. java.io.IOException: Got error, status message opReadBlock BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643:blk_1073773956_33167 received exception java.io.IOException:  Offset 16320 and length 20 don't match block BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643:blk_1073773956_33167 ( blockLen 0 ), for OP_READ_BLOCK, self=/192.168.250.202:55915, remote=/192.168.250.12:50010, for file /accumulo/tables/1/default_tablet/F0000gne.rf, for pool BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643 block 1073773956_33167
java.io.IOException: Got error, status message opReadBlock BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643:blk_1073773956_33167 received exception java.io.IOException:  Offset 16320 and length 20 don't match block BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643:blk_1073773956_33167 ( blockLen 0 ), for OP_READ_BLOCK, self=/192.168.250.202:55915, remote=/192.168.250.12:50010, for file /accumulo/tables/1/default_tablet/F0000gne.rf, for pool BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643 block 1073773956_33167
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.DataTransferProtoUtil.checkBlockOpStatus(DataTransferProtoUtil.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.checkSuccess(RemoteBlockReader2.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.RemoteBlockReader2.newBlockReader(RemoteBlockReader2.java:424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReader(BlockReaderFactory.java:818)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getRemoteBlockReaderFromTcp(BlockReaderFactory.java:697)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:355)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.blockSeekTo(DFSInputStream.java:618)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:844)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:896)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:697)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readShort(DataInputStream.java:312)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.rfile.bcfile.Utils$Version.<init>(Utils.java:264)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.rfile.bcfile.BCFile$Reader.<init>(BCFile.java:823)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.blockfile.impl.CachableBlockFile$Reader.init(CachableBlockFile.java:246)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.blockfile.impl.CachableBlockFile$Reader.getBCFile(CachableBlockFile.java:257)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.blockfile.impl.CachableBlockFile$Reader.access$100(CachableBlockFile.java:137)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.blockfile.impl.CachableBlockFile$Reader$MetaBlockLoader.get(CachableBlockFile.java:209)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.blockfile.impl.CachableBlockFile$Reader.getBlock(CachableBlockFile.java:313)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.blockfile.impl.CachableBlockFile$Reader.getMetaBlock(CachableBlockFile.java:368)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.blockfile.impl.CachableBlockFile$Reader.getMetaBlock(CachableBlockFile.java:137)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.rfile.RFile$Reader.<init>(RFile.java:843)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.rfile.RFileOperations.openReader(RFileOperations.java:79)
        at org.apache.accumulo.core.file.DispatchingFileFactory.openReader(DispatchingFileFactory.java:69)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.Compactor.openMapDataFiles(Compactor.java:279)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.Compactor.compactLocalityGroup(Compactor.java:322)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.Compactor.call(Compactor.java:214)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.Tablet._majorCompact(Tablet.java:1976)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.Tablet.majorCompact(Tablet.java:2093)
        at org.apache.accumulo.tserver.tablet.CompactionRunner.run(CompactionRunner.java:44)
        at org.apache.htrace.wrappers.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.accumulo.fate.util.LoggingRunnable.run(LoggingRunnable.java:35)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I think it is more of a HDFS related issue as opposed to an Accumulo one, so I checked the logs of the datanode and found the same message,

```
Offset 16320 and length 20 don't match block BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643:blk_1073773956_33167 ( blockLen 0 ), for OP_READ_BLOCK, self=/192.168.250.202:55915, remote=/192.168.250.12:50010, for file /accumulo/tables/1/default_tablet/F0000gne.rf, for pool BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643 block 1073773956_33167
```

But as INFO in the logs. What I don't understand is that why am I getting this error.

I can see that the pool name of the file (BP-1881591466-192.168.1.111-1438767154643) that I am trying to access contains a IP address (192.168.1.111) which does not match the IP address of any of the servers (self and remote). Actually, 192.168.1.111 was the old IP address of the  Hadoop Master server, but I had changed it. I use domain names instead of IP addresses so the only place where I made the changes were in the host files of the machines in the cluster. None of the Hadoop/Accumulo configurations use IP addresses. Does anyone know what the issue is here? I have spent days on it and still am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving indicates that Accumulo cannot read part of one of its files from HDFS. The NameNode is reporting that a block is located on a particular DataNode (in your case, `192.168.250.12`). However, when Accumulo attempts to read from that DataNode, it fails.

This likely indicates a corrupt block in HDFS, or a temporary network issue. You can try to run `hadoop fsck /` (the exact command may vary, depending on version) to perform a health check of HDFS.

Also, the IP address mismatch in the DataNode appears to indicate that the DataNode is confused about the HDFS pool it is a part of. You should restart that DataNode after double-checking its configuration, DNS, and `/etc/hosts` for any anomolies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say restart, do you mean I need to format the namenode and then start the hadoop services or simply do a ./stop-dfs.sh and then a ./start-dfs.sh?

Comment: I checked the hosts file of the cluster and the IP addresses there are correct. It seems the old IP address is cached somewhere and the hadoop ends up using those cached IP addresses but I am not sure.

Comment: I just meant stop/start dfs.

Comment: Probably best to ask on the user@hadoop.apache.org mailing list, since it appears to be an HDFS issue with your data node.